# output material is not same like preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blenderkit

I'm trying to make some ice texture and I found in net to use online material library from blenderkit but the problem is why the output/render
not same like in the preview? Can somebody explain why? I've tried *Material Properties -> Settings -> Displacement* (displacement only)

Blend files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_E2oCDpckqsvxCh5E9FherHO3OKOmneC/view

[image: here]

Comment: Could be that you're applying the material to slightly different geometry.  But it's more likely an issue with scale.  Have you selected your object in object mode and applied the scale (Shortcut: CTRL-A and select scale.)

Comment: I agree with @MartyFouts this seems like a scaling issue

Comment: @MartyFouts I've followed the instructions, but still the same nothing happened, should I share my files?? 
sorry if my grammer broken 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdYf3.jpg

Comment: sharing your files always helps! so yes, you should!

Comment: Here is how to add a blend file: Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

Comment: @MartyFouts sorry sir maybe i cant share my file,and i think the main promblem is the file it self ive try another fileand it works, really appreciate the help from all of you sir [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3ye3.jpg

Comment: Hi Hankhkim. Your file is just to big. So you can either use another cloudservice like google drive, Dropbox etc or you try to reduce the file size if your blend file

Comment: @Chris thank you sir, the link download is already added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a similar result to the preview try this:

Add a new sphere:

[image]

Give it the icy material

[image]

change scale to 0.07

then apply scale

[image]

subdivide 2 times and shade smooth and you will get:

[image]

even more subdiv:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir that's really work :)

Comment: you are welcome. So please check the checkmark left to my answer! Thank you!

Comment: sorry sir but my reputation is 11 not enough for check the checkmark at least 15 to check

Comment: normally everybody can check the checkmark -> this is the checkmark : [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4EnK.png it's AFAIK not depending on reputation. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers